# PowerShell script to remove extra comma from txt file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

We have a process that loads a daily bank file (txt format) into another system and we have noticed this process fails if an extra comma appears between the first and last name. We currently manually fix this by finding the error line and removing the offending comma and resaving the file. This issue has started to occur more frequently now and on random lines so I'm trying to see if there is say a PowerShell script I can create that will look for and remove offending comma should one appear.

A sample of the text file looks like this:

```
206985,23034038,1,62,206985,60715093,0098,00000019600,DERBYSHIRE S      ,20456461          ,                  , 17195
206985,23034038,1,62,206209,23511456,0005,00000010000,BRYANS C          ,20499987          ,                  , 17195
206985,23034038,1,62,203351,83878848,0006,00000005000,JM HARVEY         ,20560148          ,                  , 17195
206985,23034038,1,62,202542,43608352,0032,00000010389,INGLIS P E        ,21775660          ,                  , 17195
206985,23034038,1,62,209263,30535818,0016,00000018000,MUZONDO F         ,22194301          ,                  , 17195
206985,23034038,1,62,205568,90105171,0092,00000010000,ADKIN ,AM          ,22363046          ,                  , 17195
```

As you can see in the last line there is an extra comma between the last and firstname. I need a script that would remove this before the file gets processed as usual.

Is this possible?

The filename also begins "camt.xxx.barc.stm_" and the remainder is made up of a ref number which changes daily so for example:

```
camt.xxx.barc.stm_D20170714_R7741261
camt.xxx.barc.stm_D20170720_R8447561
```

Comment: You seem to have a fixed-width format there, so you just need to remove commas from the substring from character 55 through 72.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea of the syntax for this though. I really am a powershell novice.

Comment: SO is not a replacement for a tutorial. You're expected to have at least a basic understanding of the language you're trying to use. See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692804.aspx) for a starting point on working with strings in PowerShell.

Comment: Apologies. i will take a look thanks for the help.